# The reason behind HTML5 restricts charset to be compatible with ASCII and using at least 8 bits

Tags: html, security

I read this sentence in Mozilla MDN: [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5)

> Note that HTML5 restricts character sets to those compatible with
>   ASCII and using at least 8 bits. This was done to tighten security and
>   prevent some types of attacks

My question is How it's tighten the security and prevent which types of attacks?

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr39/